# where to place clientaccesspolicy.xml file into the apache tomcat server deployed in eclipse IDE

Tags: web-services

I have a silverlight application and i want to call a apache cxf web service written in java in my eclipse and published on apache tomcat 7.0 through eclipse.

so now when i call this web service from my silverlight application from visual studio 2010 i get follwing error:

*An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://localhost:8080/complesxtypeWebService/services/CompanyServicePort'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services*

when i search for this on web i found that i need to place clientaccesspolicy.xml file in the root directory of domain service.

so my problem is where to place this xml file . can it be placed somewhere in eclipse project folder or somewhere in apache tomcat folder. please let me know where to actually place this file.

my all development are done locally and everything is being tested locally.

thanks
vicky

Answer (score 1):

I placed the clientaccesspolicy.xml file in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\ROOT and it works for me.

Please note that this is Windows 7 PC and if I remove the file, I get the dreaded cross domain error.